# How to find the median number of events per year? Pandas group by datascience question

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-science, median

I have a dataset where each row is an an event of terrorism and I want to find the median number of people killed per attack in each country-year unit. In df1, each row is an event of terrorism with columns iyear, country, nkill, and NumbAttack. in df2, each row is a country-year unit, with columns country, iyear, totalnkill, NumbAttackperYear, and MedKillperAttack.

STARTING WITH df1:

| country | iyear | nkill | NumbAttack |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nigeria | 2000 | 4 | 1 |
| Nigeria | 2000 | 7 | 1 |
| Nigeria | 2000 | 10 | 1 |
| Nigeria | 2002 | 10 | 1 |
| Mali | 2000 | 2 | 1 |
| Mali | 2000 | 12 | 1 |
| Mali | 2000 | 17 | 1 |
| Mali | 2001 | 12 | 1 |
| Mali | 2001 | 15 | 1 |

ENDING WITH df2:
| country| iyear | totalnkill | NumbAttackPerYear| MedKillperAttack|
| -------- | -------- |---------|------------|------------|
| Nigeria  | 2000     |   21    |     3      |     7      |
| Nigeria  | 2001     |   0     |     0      |     0      |
| Nigeria  | 2002     |   10    |     1      |     10     |
| Mali     | 2000     |   21    |     3      |     12     |
| Mali     | 2001     |   27    |     2      |    13.5    |

I understand how to use group by to get the totalnkill and NumbAttack:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['country', 'iyear'])['nkill', 'NumbAttack'].sum()
```

Then renaming the columns:

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'nkill': 'totalnkill', 'NumbAttack': 'NumbAttackperYear'})
```

This part works! But I can't figure out an algorithm or an idea of how to find the Median number of people killed per attack for each country year unit. I get how you could take an average by just deviding totalnkill by NumbAttackperYear, but not Median. I'm really new to coding so I have trouble understanding the information in documentation etc, please help!! It would be great if you can explain what you are doing if it is complicated so I can learn. Thanks!

Comment: You can just use `.median()` to calculate the median: `df1.groupby(['country', 'iyear'])['nkill', 'NumbAttack'].median()`.  [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pandas-groupby-and-computing-median/) is an example of it being used.

Comment: Thanks! I see how this works for nkill where I want the median, but then numbAttack is just 1 for all the entries in df2 when I actually want to use .sum() for that. How can I do both .median() and .sum()?

Comment: `df1.groupby(['country', 'iyear']).agg({'nkill': 'sum', 'NumbAttack': 'median'})`  `Agg` can be found in the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)